# ionic build number wrong in config.xml file

Tags: android, ionic-framework, compilation, android-manifest

My problem is that if I compile my project, it adds a **2** to the build number.

My Ionic config.xml

```
<widget id="at.company.or.so" version="0.0.1" ios-CFBundleVersion="55" android-versionCode="72" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="72" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="at.tiddlr.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

If i build a debug or release Version should be 0.0.1(72) but when i install the App it is 0.0.1(722)

Output of aapt `aapt d badging apk.apk`

```
package: name='at.company.or.so' versionCode='722' 
versionName='0.0.1'platformBuild
VersionName='5.1.1-1819727'
sdkVersion:'14'
targetSdkVersion:'22'
```

I think it's a problem while compiling but i have no idea where to search.

Comment: I do not understand your question..

Comment: are you sure your android:versioncde="72" because my android:versionCode="1" can you please tell me the version of Ionic which you are using and the sdk of android also

Comment: @sioesi : It always adds a 2 to the versionCode.
If the versionCode in the AndroidManifest.xml is 13, the versionCode of the apk is 132. If 14 it is 142 and so on

Comment: @Anilkumar : Yess i increment the versionCode manually.
ionic --version : 1.6.4
Android sdk: 24.3.3

Comment: can you please post your code in github ... I will take a look and i will tell you

Comment: @Anilkumar: I created a new project and uploaded it to github.
Note: In this project it adds a 8. 72->728 (see readme.txt)
https://github.com/MazzMazz/wrongBuildNumber

Comment: Ok i will check it and i will ping you soon

Comment: I checked your code when I compiled and run it is not changing the android:versioncode for me it is having the old value only as "72" but the problem for your version changing is due to sdk's which you installed 24.3.3  here we are targeting the android version as "22" so android sdk="22" (5.1.1) sdk is enough....just please check with this installation and remove the advance version and try it once

Comment: Have you checked your apk File with "aapt d badging apk.apk"? In the AndroidManifest.xml it says 72 but in the apk it's 722.  
I already installed the SDK Platform for Android 5.1.1(API 22) and Android SDK Tools 24.3.3

Comment: I'm having the same problem. `android-versionCode` always add number `2` . So whenever i put `android-versionCode=3`, when build, it will automatically add `2` and become `32`.

Comment: I tried it on my Mac with a complete new installation of ionic, npm and a new project with the same result.

Comment: I can verify this as well, although in my project it adds '8'. This extra number does not get added to the manifest file, only to the apk.

Comment: Same like me, but still no solution for this. annoying...

Comment: Have you considered filing this as a bug in the [Ionic project](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic)?

Comment: here we go: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4684

Comment: It is possible to have multiple APK's per release. For example if you use Crosswalk, it will build two APK's, one for x86 platforms and one for armeabi-v7a platforms. I have a project with androidVersioncode="25" and my release has two APK's, 252 and 254. My next release will have 262 and 264. And that's not a problem as both releases have a versionName="1.0.7" and only this name is visible for the end user.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you still have an issue with this, but I ran into the same build issue with Android where mine would increment with an 8.  My solution for now is to..... dramatic pause.... comment out some lines in the build.gradle file.  Whenever I upgrade the CLI I have to go do it again....

This line:

```
versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode") + "0")
```

Change to:

```
versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
```

Then I also comment out the whole if/else block about 13 lines down which starts with:

```
if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
```

Now I have to manually update my build number for android before I deploy to the store in the config file, but my increment issue has stopped.  Hopefully this help somebody out if you have already passed the issue.  I have included a link to the issue on Apache's issues board below.  IF the link ever dies check out CB-8976 on Apache's issue site.  I will also note that I have not experienced any issues with commenting this out... but I can not guarantee since you should not mess with this file technically as they state // GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!)

[Apache Issue's / Version Code](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8976?jql=text%20~%20%22versionCode%22)

Comment: This problem with the Ionic CLI is alive and well.